# UITableViewDataSource Done Loading Signal to UITableViewDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have separate files for the **UITableViewDataSource** and **UITableViewDelegate**

I am implementing a 'Pull Down to Refresh' feature on a UITableView and wish to send a signal from the **UITableViewDataSource** to the **UITableViewDelegate** to stop the loading indicator from turning.

I was wondering what the best way to send a signal between the **UITableViewDataSource** and **UITableViewDelegate** is, or if there is a better way to construct this since I feel like I'm breaking some abstraction barriers.

What I have in the Data Source:

```
if([tableView.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData)]){
    [tableView.delegate dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData];
}
```

but I get 'dataSourceDidFinishLoadingNewData' not found in protocol warning since, I guess, the function is not declared as a method of **UITableViewDelegate**

Comment: Are you just using a single controller for both the DataSource and delegate? I wouldn't be too worried about mixing the two. It pretty much already feels like they're one and the same (and in fact in any  UITableViewController subclass, they are).

Comment: Under my current setup I have two UITableViews under one view controller, so I have two data sources and one delegate - so I'd rather keep separate files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a side answer; When using the:

```
if([object respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod)]){
    [object someMethod];
}
```

paradigm, you can just use this instead:

```
if([object respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod)]){
    [object performSelector:@selector(someMethod)];
}
```

Might be a little lengthier, but it won't give you any warnings.

Comment: It's because performSelector only knows what method is being called at run-time. That means that during compile time, it can't detect whether a certain message is listed in the interface or not. It's kind of a double-edged sword.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are aware, but there are multiple open-source implementations of pull-to-refresh. You might want to look into those before making your own. Here is one (just the first one on Google): http://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh

Comment: thanks, I am using this version: http://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Answer (score 0):

You propably can't do this while keeping things completely abstract. An alternative to calling the delegate via the tableViews delegate property would be exchanging an keeping references. But you could even avoid the need to keep references to each other object by using notifications to signal the delegate that loading has finished.

Check [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.